# No suitably rooted paths error when trying to set action on object

Tags: python, actions

I'm trying to place a copy of an action onto another object.
My code seems to work, except when I try to set the action on the new object.
(I'm copying the animated viewport display rgb values, from the material of source_cube to the viewport display colors of target_cube)

The error that eludes me is:
Error: Could not set action 'the_new_action.002' onto ID 'OBtarget', as it does not have suitably rooted paths for this purpose

Any clues what I'm missing here?

```
import bpy

# Gets the action from material of object
def get_material_action(object):
    # current_object, material, action
    current_material = object.material_slots[0].material
    action = current_material.animation_data.action
    print ('getter: found:', action.name)
    return action
    
    #print ('current object', current_object.name)
    #print ('current material', current_material.name)
    #print ('current material action', current_material_action.name)

# Copies the action
def copy_action(action):
    current_action = bpy.data.actions.get(action)
    
    ### Create a copy of that action
    new_action = current_action.copy()
    new_action.name = 'the_new_action'
    print ('copier made: ', new_action.name)
    return new_action
    
# Sets the action on material of object    
def set_action(object, new_action):
    current_material = object.material_slots[0].material
    # create empty action
    object.animation_data_create()
    object.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.get(new_action.name)


# Define source and target objects
source_object = bpy.data.objects['source']
target_object = bpy.data.objects['target']


# get current action from source 
# Then copy and name it
# Then set action on target
source_action = get_material_action(source_object)    
new_action = copy_action(source_action.name)
set_action(target_object, new_action)



print ('done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Action ID root**

The error is informing of attempting  to link an action which expects to be for a material onto an object.

The created action from keyframing property of  a material has 'MATERIAL' set as its ID root.

> **[ID root](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Action.html#bpy.types.Action.Action.id_root)**
>
> Type of ID block that action can  be used on - DO NOT CHANGE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING

Py console example

```
>>> source = C.object
>>> mat = source.active_material
>>> mat
bpy.data.materials['Material']

>>> action = mat.animation_data.action
>>> action
bpy.data.actions['MaterialAction']

>>> action.id_root
'MATERIAL'
```

An object's action  would expect this value to be 'OBJECT'.

**Material action -> Object action**

Example, material action with only keyframes for  `diffuse_color` of material

```
>>> for f in action.fcurves:
...     f.data_path, f.array_index
...     
('diffuse_color', 0)
('diffuse_color', 1)
('diffuse_color', 2)
('diffuse_color', 3)
```

the data path from an object to "viewport color" is  `color`

At the very simplest, could as above copy the action, iterate over the fcurves, make our necessary datapath change, set object id root  and assign to the object.

```
action = action.copy()
for fc in action.fcurves:
    fc.data_path.replace("diffuse_color", "color")
action.id_root = 'OBJECT'
```

**Context**

Customary in blender is to use the active object as a source and other selected objects as the destination.

```
source = context.object
targets = context.selected_objects
targets.remove(source)
```

for operators, having a `poll` method removes the need to test for  `context.object` being `None`

Comment: worked like a charm when I set it up that way.
Thank you batFINGER