Python Runtime Error during FBX export: Could not set action as it does not have suitably rooted paths for this purpose
I’m trying to export to FBX, but I keep getting the following error:

RuntimeError: Error: Could not set action 'Action.001' onto ID 'OBText', as it does not have suitably rooted paths for this purpose



Reading through the traceback, it relates to animation actions. How is the object animated? Does it have any NLA strips applied? Does it have more than one action?

Does the answer in this thread help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195005/no-suitably-rooted-paths-error-when-trying-to-set-action-on-object If you believe it's different please explain how it is different then we can re-open.
